# How to add link_after and lin_before class in Wordpress wp_nav_menu?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Now i have a problem to add extra two span class, like this

```
<li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15"><a href="#"><span class="left"></span>Sample Page<span class="right"></span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) you can supply strings to appear before and after the link text using the 'link_before' and 'link_after' parameters.

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
  'link_before' => '<span class="left"></span>',
  'link_after' => '<span class="right"></span>'
));
```